# Using ternary operator in MySQLi query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, ternary

I want to use ternary operation in my MYSQLi query. I have searched the forum and found an answers how its done, but in my case its not working at all. I will post what I tried:

```
$topsearch_listings = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE published='yes' AND topsearch=1 ".$selected_category == 'All' ? '' : 'AND category='$selected_category''." ORDER BY rand()");
```

So what Im trying to do is if selected category is equal to `"All"` do nothing, and if selected category isnt equal to All add `AND category='$selected_category'`. What is wrong with my ternary and how can I use it inside my query?

Comment: use double quotes ```"AND category='$selected_category' "``` and wrap whole ternary operator into round brackets ```"hi ". ( $cond ? "sis" : "bro")." blah blah"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query like that is nothing more than just a string so treat it the same - the operator needs to know where are its boundries - therefore:

```
$topsearch_listings = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE published='yes' AND topsearch=1 ". ($selected_category == 'All' ? '' : 'AND category=\''.$selected_category.'\'')  ." ORDER BY rand()");
```

Be sure yet to know that it is not safe to execute queries like this. I would suggest executing DIFFERENT queries for the open case (All) and particular ones (where there is a category). Plus you should use bound variables or at least try to escape the input.

Comment: Thanks man, it works!
Also I'm aware of the SQL Injections but im using mysqli_real_escape_string on $selected_category POST variable. So if I'm not planning to run this for larger audience I think I'm safe with the mysqli real escape string, or I'm not?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
$cond = $selected_category == 'All' ? "" : " AND category='$selected_category' ";

$topsearch_listings = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM listing WHERE published='yes' AND topsearch=1 ".$cond."  ORDER BY rand()");
```

It's good practice to use
**MySQLi Prepared Statements**
Read more about it here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php